# Zend Framework: Select the greatest number from table columns

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

How can I select the greatest number from table columns, exp. that is my table:

> id|name|views|
>      1|test|42|
>      2|test1|89|
>      3|test2|4|
>      4|test3|35|

I need to select all values for row id 2, because views is most greatest number from other views? I try this, but don't work:

```
$q = $this->select()->from($this->_name, array(new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(views)'), 'id', 'name'))->order('name DESC')->limit(1)->group('name');

return $this->fetchRow($q);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
$q = $this->select()
        ->from($this->_name, array('id', 'name'))
        ->order('views DESC')
        ->limit(1);
return $this->fetchRow($q);
```

**Hint:**

*`Apply ORDER BY views DESC, and then LIMIT 1`*